# Choosing RGB color in Illustrator (when only CMYK sliders are visible)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, laser-cutting

I'm making a simple template to laser cut. The laser cutter acts as a printer and you choose the power, speed, etc. for each colour that is in the document. I only want to cut, so I only have RGB red lines at 0.001 pt thickness. Or at least that was the plan. One of the shapes in my template has come out a different red (the swatches were CMYK despite the document colour mode being RGB). I would now like to select all the paths in the document and make them all RGB red. However, when I open the colour panel from the dock the sliders are CMYK, again this is despite the document colour mode being RGB:

[image: RGB document colour mode but CMYK sliders screenshot]

How do I change all the paths to be RGB red?

How do I stop Illustrator offering me CMYK options and swatches and offering RGB instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not realise that RGB was also an option under the fly-out (the right arrow(s) in the upper right corner of the Color palette).

It's also worth note that I should (could?) have chosen the document color mode by selecting a correct new document profile in "New document" dialog box.

Jacob Bugge and Monika Gause pointed them out for me on the Adobe Forums http://forums.adobe.com/message/5675180